# Splitting a large file and rsync the file as each file is splt and not waiting for rest

Tags: rsync

```
ls -lrt
-rw-rw-r--    1 rose     user      7516081152 Apr 10 15:47 bak1


split -b 1024m bak1 

-rw-rw-r--    1 rose     user      1073741824 Apr 10 17:15 xaa
-rw-rw-r--    1 rose     user      1073741824 Apr 10 17:16 xab
-rw-rw-r--    1 rose     user      1073741824 Apr 10 17:16 xac
-rw-rw-r--    1 rose     user      1073741824 Apr 10 17:16 xad
-rw-rw-r--    1 rose     user      1073741824 Apr 10 17:16 xae
-rw-rw-r--    1 rose     user       343805952 Apr 10 17:16 xaf
```

For a very large file it can take up to 20 minutes to split a single file.

So this is my objective:

As the first file is split,  I will like to rsync it to a remote server B, without waiting for the 2nd split to finish and so forth up to the last file.
I want  to loop until the last file is split,  which most likely will have a smaller size than the rest.

I have been struggling to come up with a script, I tried to tinker with comparing the checksum value but it is not working.
I wanted to check the size, but since I will not know the exact size after the split, I am not if I can use it. Especially if I schedule the script to run
I hope some of you gurus can pull this off for me

- AIX

CHECKING THE SUM

```
for bfile in `ls -lrt .|grep bak|awk '{print $NF}'`;
do
    sum1="$(csum -h MD5 "$bfile")"
    sleep 2
    sum2="$(csum -h MD5 "$file")"
    if [ "$sum1" = "$sum2" ];
    then
        echo "$bfile size has not changed in the last 3 secs. I am going to ship it"
    else
        echo "$bfile size keep changing in size. i will have to wait"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Does your `split` support `--filter` option?

Comment: Maybe rsync with partial flag (`-P` / `--partial`), it's no issue to transfer the second part while you still split as even if it is only partially transferred, the next rsync call will continue and transfer the rest. which might even be an option to not split the file at all and just transfer it in whole.

Comment: I don't get why you'd not just transfer the file as a whole if you're waiting for the sequential splitting anyway? As for your script you could just use the size and transfer the last file after split ends as only the last file should have a different size?